# Find text within string line

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a text file, that has some text with this syntax:

mytextfile.txt:

```
websiteurl1 username1 password1  
websiteurl2 username2 password2                                       
websiteurl3 username3 password3
```

And so on....

And I'd like to be able to find username and password strings by pointing the websiteurl, so let's say I tell the batch file,
find websiteurl3, it should print the username3 and password3
and I was able to write a "FOR LOOP" but I am not sure how to use the syntax of the loop, as my code finds only the last line always, here is what I have:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2,3 delims= " %%A IN (URL.txt) DO IF EXIST URL.txt (set WEBUserName1=%%A) && (SET WEBUserPass1=%%B)  
pause
echo Username:"%WEBUserName1%"
echo Password:"%WEBUserPass1%"
pause
exit
```

I know the loop is looking on the "URL.txt" for the tokens 2 and 3, and then sets the variables accordingly, what I'd like to know, is how I can use the loop, or if needed, any other command to be able to:

- Find the "URL.txt file
- Then find the specific string, in this case, the first word of the specified string line
- Then find tokens 2 and 3 of that string line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### And I'd like to be able to find username and password strings

Use the following batch file.

**test.cmd:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2,3" %%a in ('type mytextfile.txt ^| findstr "%1"') do (
  echo Username:"%%a"
  echo Password:"%%b"
  pause
  exit
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Pass the website URL string as a parameter to the batch file.
- `findstr` is used to find the matching line from the file, so we only need to parse a single line using `for /f`.

**Example usage and output:**

```
F:\test>type mytextfile.txt
websiteurl1 username1 password1
websiteurl2 username2 password2
websiteurl3 username3 password3

F:\test>test websiteurl3
Username:"username3"
Password:"password3"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [type](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) - Display the contents of one or more text files.

Answer (score 0):

You get the last line, because you process the whole file. Filter your textfile and process only that one line:

```
set "site=websiteurl2"
FOR /F "tokens=2,3 delims= " %%A IN ('find "%site%" URL.txt') DO (
  set "usr=%%A" 
  set "pwd=%%B"
)
echo %usr%, %pwd%
```

Comment: "process the whole line" should be "process the whole file"?

Answer (score 0):

bad way, but this too work:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set srch_site=websiteurl2
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%A IN (URL.txt) DO (
    IF EXIST URL.txt (
        if "%%A"=="%srch_site%" (
            (set WEBUserName1=%%B) && (SET WEBUserPass1=%%C)&goto:stdout
        )
    )
)
:stdout
pause
echo Username:"%WEBUserName1%"
echo Password:"%WEBUserPass1%"
pause
exit
```

Comment: The `IF EXIST URL.txt (` line have no sense in this place. If the file does not exist, an error is issued in the _previous_ `FOR /F` command. If the file does exist, the `IF EXIST` command is executed _with every line_ in the file...

Comment: @Aacini, of course ;)) i just copypast and then edit example of the code from the question.. with least changes

Answer (score 0):

May I offer you a different approach?

The code below get *all usernames and passwords* and store they in two vectors:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1-3" %%A in (URL.txt) do set "User[%%A]=%%B" & set "Pass[%%A]=%%C"
```

After that, you may *test* if the username and password of a certain site was given this way:

```
set "site=websiteurl3"

if defined User[%site%] echo The site "%site%" have username and password
```

... or *display* their values this way:

```
echo Username:"!User[%site%]!"
echo Password:"!Pass[%site%]!"
```

You may review a detailed explanation of array management in Batch files at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).